# PerformanceCounter. How do I access the right process if the same ones are running?

Tags: vb.net

```
        Dim pc As New PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process Id",_
        Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName)
        Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcessById(CInt(pc.RawValue))
        CloseName = p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileName
```

When you run multiple copies of the program gives an error. How to address to the necessary process if there are several with identical names?

ex.Message = " Process ID 16020 is not running."

Comment: `Creating Process Id` returns the ID of the Process that created the *Current*. For example, if you lauch your program from Explorer, it will be `Explorer.exe`, `Cmd.exe` if started from a console prompt. If the process that started the `InstanceName` you're referring to is already closed (the starting process is a stub or it exits immediately after lauching another process instance), then you won't find it's ProcessId. You can replicate this behavior using an app to run another, calling `Application.Exit()` in the *launcher* right after `Process.Start()`.

Comment: All of this Yes. When you run the copy as I understand it the following happens. There is a request who started this program and the name of the current program is transferred, but the program with this name in the Manager already exists. And I need to know exactly who launched the second, and the answer comes back to the first. Hope not confused.

Comment: В "Creating Process Id" передается имя программы, что делать если таких имен одинаковых в диспетчере много. Как найти нужный.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to let a **previous** instance of your application know what process started a **second** instance of it. If this is the case, see the different [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) features. Usually, [Windows Communication Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/) or [Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication) are used for this.

Comment: App 1 starts, it starts app 2. Annex 2 checks to see who started it(Creating a Process Id).  At the same time, the second pair of applications starts and does the same thing. And the problem is that they confuse each other.